# Protractor automation test - move element to placeholder

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, protractor, automated-tests

## Problem:

I'm working on regression tests for dashboard with widgets.

One of my test case needs to check if drag and drop of widgets is working correctly.
As an assertion, I will count how many widgets were from the left side, will move one to the right side, so on the left side should be -1 element.

Browser: Chrome

Test case:

1. Website looks like the photo. View is divided into two containers (left and right), when in each are widgets(blue elements)

[image: initial view]

CSS: 
[image: clicking on element]

2. To move a widget from left to right side I need to click at the element and move to the right side.

Just after I moved a little bit, the "Placeholder" would appear(grey box)
[image: firs tstage]

CSS: 
[image: while moving]

3. While moving to the right side of the screen, "placeholder" will be created in the second container and disappeared from the first.

[image: just before drop]

CSS first and second container:
[image: just before drop]

## What I've tried:

Because there is no drop container visible all the time (placeholder is created only while moving element) I'm not able to use `.dragAndDrop()` method.

Question: 
can anyone advise how can I simulate such test?

Comment: There is a known issue with drag and drop and Chrome. I would link the docs but it looks like they've actually removed dragAndDrop altogether from the APi reference page. In any case, use `html-dnd` package instead for drag and drop. It works for Chrome. My guess is that's why it's not working.

Comment: Wait, so if this is the only reason why you can't do it, just drop it on the first element of the right column... so the app will do the rest

Comment: secondly, I try to not use dragAndDrop, because you can achieve the same with chaining mouseDown().move().mouseUp().perform(), but you'll have more functionality with more stable performance. move() method can accept an elementFinder or even offset positions. If for whatever reasons you can't move to specific element you may find a workaroud to move to (current location + 150px), or get location of needed element and pass it